# How to display an image saved as "/storage/emulated/0/Download/IMG_1582623402006.jpg" in emulator

Tags: android-studio, imageview

I capture a image by camera in emulator and it was saved as:

```
"/storage/emulated/0/Download/IMG_1582623402006.jpg"
```

I am trying to display this image in < ImageView > as the following:

```
 Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/IMG_1582623402006.jpg");
 holder.image.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

but it shows that "finalBitmap" is empty. What have I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried the same code using a physical phone and the image seems displayed but there are large margin/padding around the image though "finalBitmap" still shows empty.

Answer (score 1):

You posted this over a year ago, so it may be too old at this point.

It appears that you are using two variables for your bitmaps: `finalBitmap` and `scaledBitmap` and not referencing the proper one in the `setImageBitmap` command.

Instead, have you tried this?

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure, but adding some attributes in "options" seems make it work in emulator:

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = true;
options.inSampleSize = 5;
Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(/storage/emulated/0/Download/IMG_1582623402006.jpg, options);
holder.image.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```